# List of databases in one table, querying tables from those databases in one SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have many databases on an SQL 2005 server.
There is a main database called 'siteadmin' which has a table 'PROJECTS' which has a column 'DB_NAME' which lists the names of other databases.

I need to iterate through each of those names of databases performing a count and max query on the table called 'BUG' which exists in each database.

This is the best I have come up with so far:

```
USE siteadmin
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @iRowCount INT
SET @iRowCount = 0
WHILE @iRowCount < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROJECTS)

BEGIN
    SELECT @dbname = DB_NAME FROM PROJECTS WHERE PROJECT_ID = @iRowCount

    USE @dbname
    select
        SQ_SEQ_VALUE,
        (select count(BG_BUG_ID) from td.BUG) TotalBUGs,
        (select max(BG_BUG_ID) from td.BUG) MaxBUGID
    from td.SEQUENCES
    WHERE sq_seq_name='BUG'

    SET @iRowCount = @iRowCount + 1
    CONTINUE
END
```

It fails on the 'USE @dbname' statement.

Each of the databases have the same 'BUG' table and I need to get the max bug ID and the number of actual bugs.
So I need to end up with a list like:

```
        SQ_SEQ_VALUE, TotalBUGs, MaxBUGID  
dbname1 123           150        170  
dbname2 165           165        165  
dbname3 176           176        176
```

I have a feeling I have gone in a totally wrong direction.
Is anyone able to help?

Comment: `USE` needs a real database name. It can't use a variable. Unfortunately, that means some dynamic SQL in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd scenario, but I assume you have good reason for it.

If you can trust the values that will be stored in the DB_NAME column of the PROJECTS table, you should be able to switch the active database by using `EXEC 'USE [' + @dbname + ']'` instead.

You will have to ensure that the user has permissions to read from each database you need to connect to as well.  There may be a better methods to accomplish this task, but with minimal change to what you have I would expect this to work.

Comment: I had to make @RowCount = 1 and do what you did enclosed in ()'s, now it says it can't find the 'BUG' table, which is definitely present in every database. Hmmm...

Comment: And you have the bug table as part of a schema called `td`? Can you provide the exact error text?

Comment: Sorry yeah the table is actually called 'td.BUG'.  I meant to remove the td. part from my example to avoid creating confusion but I missed it. I have finally figured it out after hours of trial and error (and googling), thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using:

```
USE siteadmin
DECLARE @sqlq VARCHAR(1500)  -- sql query
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100) -- database name  

DECLARE dbnamescursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DB_NAME FROM PROJECTS;

OPEN dbnamescursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbnamescursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    IF (db_id(@dbname) is not null)
    BEGIN

        SET @sqlq = 'SELECT ''' + @dbname + ''' as Databasename, Count([' + @dbname + '].[td.BUG].BG_BUG_ID) as TotalBUGs, Max([' + @dbname + '].[td.BUG].BG_BUG_ID) as MaxBUGID
        FROM [' + @dbname + '].[td.BUG] CROSS JOIN [' + @dbname + '].SEQUENCES
        WHERE ([' + @dbname + '].SEQUENCES.SQ_SEQ_NAME = ''BUG'')
        GROUP BY [' + @dbname + '].SEQUENCES.SQ_SEQ_VALUE'

        EXEC (@sqlq)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbnamescursor INTO @dbname   
END   

CLOSE dbnamescursor   
DEALLOCATE dbnamescursor
```